# Error "CodRes. 0301 - Lote no encolado para procesamiento"

Tags: nodejs, xml, facturacion, sifen

espero poder alcanzar a programadores paraguayos con experiencia implementando la facturacion electronica. La libreria en nodejs para el envio de facturas al SIFEN que uso:
[Libreria NodeJs SET API](https://www.npmjs.com/package/facturacionelectronicapy-setapi)
Estamos en desarrollo, pero hasta ahora no he podido enviar con exito ningun lote de facturas, recibiendo siempre este error:  "CodRes. 0301 - Lote no encolado para procesamiento"
He contactado con soporte del SIFEN, he verificado el timeout para recibir respuestas del sifen (lo puse a 90 segundos inclusive), tampoco hay lotes en procesamiento (ningun lote ha podido recibirse con exito, son rechazados). El certificado digital empleado esta en orden, los datos requeridos de la factura tambien.
Incluyo aqui el XML:

```js
var xml = `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<rDE xmlns="http://ekuatia.set.gov.py/sifen/xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://ekuatia.set.gov.py/sifen/xsd siRecepDE_v150.xsd">
  <dVerFor>150</dVerFor>
  <DE Id="01800473175001001000117122023042111828400001">
    <dDVId>1</dDVId>
    <dFecFirma>2024-03-07T12:32:46</dFecFirma>
    <dSisFact>1</dSisFact>
    <gOpeDE>
      <iTipEmi>1</iTipEmi>
      <dDesTipEmi>Normal</dDesTipEmi>
      <dCodSeg>CODIGOSEGURIDAD</dCodSeg>
      <dInfoEmi>OBSERVACION ...</dInfoEmi>
      <dInfoFisc>DESCR DE FACTURA</dInfoFisc>
    </gOpeDE>
    <gTimb>
      <iTiDE>1</iTiDE>
      <dDesTiDE>Factura electrónica</dDesTiDE>
      <dNumTim>80047317</dNumTim>
      <dEst>001</dEst>
      <dPunExp>001</dPunExp>
      <dNumDoc>0001171</dNumDoc>
      <dFeIniT>2024-02-29</dFeIniT>
    </gTimb>
    <gDatGralOpe>
      <dFeEmiDE>2023-04-21T00:00:00</dFeEmiDE>
      <gOpeCom>
        <iTipTra>3</iTipTra>
        <dDesTipTra>Mixto (Venta de mercadería y servicios)</dDesTipTra>
        <iTImp>1</iTImp>
        <dDesTImp>IVA</dDesTImp>
        <cMoneOpe>PYG</cMoneOpe>
        <dDesMoneOpe>Guarani</dDesMoneOpe>
        <iCondAnt>1</iCondAnt>
        <dDesCondAnt>Anticipo Global</dDesCondAnt>
      </gOpeCom>
      <gEmis>
        <dRucEm>80047317</dRucEm>
        <dDVEmi>5</dDVEmi>
        <iTipCont>2</iTipCont>
        <cTipReg>8</cTipReg>
        <dNomEmi>A+E S.A.</dNomEmi>
        <dNomFanEmi>A+E S.A.</dNomFanEmi>
        <dDirEmi>CALLE, AVDA FULGENCIO YEGROS</dDirEmi>
        <dNumCas>0</dNumCas>
        <cDepEmi>8</cDepEmi>
        <dDesDepEmi>ITAPUA</dDesDepEmi>
        <cDisEmi>87</cDisEmi>
        <dDesDisEmi>ENCARNACION</dDesDisEmi>
        <cCiuEmi>2275</cCiuEmi>
        <dDesCiuEmi>SAN JUAN DEL PARANA</dDesCiuEmi>
        <dTelEmi>(021)7005400</dTelEmi>
        <dEmailE>info@aguav.com.py</dEmailE>
        <dDenSuc>MATRIZ</dDenSuc>
        <gActEco>
          <cActEco>68100</cActEco>
          <dDesActEco>ACTIVIDADES INMOBILIARIAS REALIZADAS CON BIENES PROPIOS O ARRENDADOS</dDesActEco>
        </gActEco>
        <gRespDE>
          <iTipIDRespDE>1</iTipIDRespDE>
          <dDTipIDRespDE>Cédula paraguaya</dDTipIDRespDE>
          <dNumIDRespDE>4747132</dNumIDRespDE>
          <dNomRespDE>SONIA TOLEDO</dNomRespDE>
          <dCarRespDE>CAJERO</dCarRespDE>
        </gRespDE>
      </gEmis>
      <gDatRec>
        <iNatRec>1</iNatRec>
        <iTiOpe>2</iTiOpe>
        <cPaisRec>PRY</cPaisRec>
        <dDesPaisRe>Paraguay</dDesPaisRe>
        <iTiContRec>1</iTiContRec>
        <dRucRec>4568959</dRucRec>
        <dDVRec>8</dDVRec>
        <dNomRec>LEONARDO ADRIAN BENITEZ</dNomRec>
        <dNomFanRec>LEONARDO ADRIAN BENITEZ</dNomFanRec>
        <dNumCasRec>0</dNumCasRec>
      </gDatRec>
    </gDatGralOpe>
    <gDtipDE>
      <gCamFE>
        <iIndPres>1</iIndPres>
        <dDesIndPres>Operación presencial</dDesIndPres>
      </gCamFE>
      <gCamCond>
        <iCondOpe>2</iCondOpe>
        <dDCondOpe>Crédito</dDCondOpe>
        <gPaConEIni>
          <iTiPago>1</iTiPago>
          <dDesTiPag>Efectivo</dDesTiPag>
          <dMonTiPag>12000</dMonTiPag>
          <cMoneTiPag>PYG</cMoneTiPag>
          <dDMoneTiPag>Guarani</dDMoneTiPag>
        </gPaConEIni>
        <gPagCred>
          <iCondCred>1</iCondCred>
          <dDCondCred>Plazo</dDCondCred>
          <dPlazoCre>30 dias</dPlazoCre>
          <dMonEnt>12000</dMonEnt>
        </gPagCred>
      </gCamCond>
      <gCamItem>
        <dCodInt>A01107</dCodInt>
        <dDesProSer>ALMUERZO ECONOMICO DIARIO</dDesProSer>
        <cUniMed>77</cUniMed>
        <dDesUniMed>UNI</dDesUniMed>
        <dCantProSer>1</dCantProSer>
        <cPaisOrig>PRY</cPaisOrig>
        <dDesPaisOrig>Paraguay</dDesPaisOrig>
        <dInfItem>ALMUERZO ECONOMICO DIARIO</dInfItem>
        <gValorItem>
          <dPUniProSer>12000.000000</dPUniProSer>
          <dTotBruOpeItem>12000</dTotBruOpeItem>
          <gValorRestaItem>
            <dDescItem>0</dDescItem>
            <dDescGloItem>0</dDescGloItem>
            <dAntPreUniIt>0</dAntPreUniIt>
            <dAntGloPreUniIt>0</dAntGloPreUniIt>
            <dTotOpeItem>12000</dTotOpeItem>
          </gValorRestaItem>
        </gValorItem>
        <gCamIVA>
          <iAfecIVA>1</iAfecIVA>
          <dDesAfecIVA>Gravado IVA</dDesAfecIVA>
          <dPropIVA>100</dPropIVA>
          <dTasaIVA>10</dTasaIVA>
          <dBasGravIVA>10909.09090909</dBasGravIVA>
          <dLiqIVAItem>1090.90909091</dLiqIVAItem>
          <dBasExe>0</dBasExe>
        </gCamIVA>
      </gCamItem>
    </gDtipDE>
    <gTotSub>
      <dSubExe>0</dSubExe>
      <dSubExo>0</dSubExo>
      <dSub5>0</dSub5>
      <dSub10>12000</dSub10>
      <dTotOpe>12000</dTotOpe>
      <dTotDesc>0</dTotDesc>
      <dTotDescGlotem>0</dTotDescGlotem>
      <dTotAntItem>0</dTotAntItem>
      <dTotAnt>0</dTotAnt>
      <dPorcDescTotal>0</dPorcDescTotal>
      <dDescTotal>0</dDescTotal>
      <dAnticipo>0</dAnticipo>
      <dRedon>0</dRedon>
      <dTotGralOpe>12000</dTotGralOpe>
      <dIVA5>0</dIVA5>
      <dIVA10>1091</dIVA10>
      <dLiqTotIVA5>0</dLiqTotIVA5>
      <dLiqTotIVA10>0</dLiqTotIVA10>
      <dTotIVA>1091</dTotIVA>
      <dBaseGrav5>0</dBaseGrav5>
      <dBaseGrav10>10909</dBaseGrav10>
      <dTBasGraIVA>10909</dTBasGraIVA>
    </gTotSub>
    <gCamGen/>
  </DE>
</rDE>`
```

Tratandose del ambiente de testing, utilizo los parametros correctos para pruebas:

- Reemplazo el numero de timbrado por el RUC del emisor (sin digito verificador)
- La fecha de inicio de vigencia de timbrado es la fecha en que se genero el formulario de habilitacion como facturador electronico.
  -Empleo el establecimiento 001, limitandome a los puntos de expedicion 001,002, 003

Abajo la respuesta completa en xml:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]